# Add timestamp to CSS id

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on some css experiments and I'd like the replicate something that is done in Adobe Edge Animate.  In that program, you are able to create 100% uniquely named divs that avoid the possibility of running into the same name divs on a website.  An example of this is ad-serving any element that requires css.  Even if I name something really_cool_container as an id, there is always the chance that I will run into a div with this name, and completely break the entire page.

Edge is able to generate your named ids as something like really_cool_container_028485020 for every instance of that container on the page.  This goes for two instances of really_cool_container that may appear on the page twice.

Edge can be limited in some respects, so I'd like to find a way to add a timestamp value to each instance (down to the ms) in order to reduce the likeliness of running into a similar id.

Edge also manages to rename the id, but in all instances of that id so that other scripts can still reference it.

Does anyone know how to do this through pure code?

Answer (score 0):

For a Javascript only way, you could try:

```
<div id="same"></div>
<div id="same"></div>
<div id="same"></div>

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0;i < divs.length;i++){
    divs[i].id += "_"+(new Date().getTime()+i);
}

<div id="same_1364844463671"></div>
<div id="same_1364844463672"></div>
<div id="same_1364844463673"></div>
```